# CURL json output cuts off

Tags: json, bash, curl, output, jq

I'm working on centos 7 and has this json request :

```
curl  --output 'json.data.json' -vvv -x ''  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"item.get","params":{"output": ["name","lastvalue","lastclock","hostid"],"groupids": ["5"],"filter":{"name":["LDT Security Flag"]},"sortfield": "name" },"auth":"c1cxxxxxxxxx","id":1}' $CURLADDR
```

Now, 
In middle of results I see :

```
734247","lastvalue":"0"},{"itemid":"192890","name":"LDT Fl* transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
100 86797    0 86569  100   228  75094    197  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 75146
* Closing connection 0
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

And after that some more json results.
But I noticed that not matter how many times I run it and redirect output to .json file , file always at the same size : **88K like there some kind of limit** on info download size ?  what can i do ?

**UPDATE:**

So i added it and now the error : curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding Read data remaining is gone. but is still cuts at the middle with :  `* Closing Connection 0` and file is 88K – Batchen Regev 11 mins ago

also connection data :

```
> POST /api_jsonrpc.php HTTP/1.0
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: XXXXXX:1080
> Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
> Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
> Content-Length: 224
>
} [data not shown]
* upload completely sent off: 224 out of 224 bytes
100   224    0     0  100   224      0    223  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   223< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 25 Dec 2018 15:21:07 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Connection: close
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
<
{ [data not shown]
100 86840    0 86616  100   224  77583    200  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 77612
* Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a server side issue. 
You might try to work it around by forcing HTTP 1.0 connection (to avoid chunked transfer which might cause this problem) with the --http1.0 option.

Comment: Hey, 
so i added it and now the error : `curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining` is gone. but is still cuts at the middle with : ` * Closing connection 0
` and file is 88K

Comment: You could try some other tool like Postman and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: i have tried YARC and it does not cut off there. thats why i think its somthing with CURL but cant figure out what. i know information is VERY big maybe thats why .. but how can i overcome this ?

Answer (score 0):

### CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE (18)

A file transfer was shorter or larger than expected. This happens when the server first reports an expected transfer size, and then delivers data that doesn't match the previously given size.

Source: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

Comment: Hey ,i added  --http1.0 option like suggested, and error 18 is gone but i get 
in middle of CURL and still data gets cut off. any more ideas ?